# Child-window's ShowDialog bubbles to DispatcherUnhandledException even when try/catch surrounds the call

Tags: .net, wpf

My main window register to `DispatcherUnhandledException` event.
When showing a simple Child window by `ShowDialog` from the UI thread (the `ShowDialog` is in a try/catch block), when an exception is thrown from the Child window (specifically in an OnClick's `EventHandler`), the `DispatcherUnhandledException`'s event handler is called, and then the catch in the scope of the call to `ShowDialog`.
I would expect that if an exception is thrown in a try/catch block, the `DispatcherUnhandledException` **would not** fired.
What am I missing?

I have noticed that [this exact problem is resolved here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timart/archive/2013/09/30/dispatcherunhandledexception-catches-children-window-exception-before-try-catch-showdialog.aspx), but it's not clear why the problem happens in the first place.

EDIT:
The following is taken from the link above, it's a simple example to reproduce this behavior:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
{
    DispatcherUnhandledException += App_OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
}

private void App_OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Handler #1 An Exception occured in the Root (App.xaml.cs)");
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ErroringWindow window = new ErroringWindow();
    try
    {
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handler #2 Exception occured in the try/catch");
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to catch. Can you please post some code ?